Getting "CheckSynchronize called from thread $5994, which is NOT the main thread" error while freeing an object
I am facing an issue in my program, where I am freeing an object CalcTree which is class type of TVirtualStringTree. This object is used in our program for calculation purposes only. So, while creating this object like below, we haven't used any parent.
T^.CalcTree               := TCalcTree.Create(nil);   
  T^.CalcTree.NodeDataSize  := SizeOf(TCalcData);
  T^.CalcTree.Visible       := FALSE;

Here T is a record object which will hold multiple objects and other properties to maintain our application data. We are using this T object for each user to maintain their information. Our application will serve the multi user requests with API calls.
After usage of that record pointer, we would like to delete the T record, so in the deleting method we have freed all the internal objects of the record and then freed it. In this process, when we try to free the CalcTree object, we are facing an exception:

CheckSynchronize called from thread $5994, which is NOT the main thread

This is the code block which raises the exception:
try
  CalcTree.free;  //raising exception
except
  ON E: Exception DO BEGIN
    TBCmd5.WriteLogDo(ServerPointer, (DateTimeToStr(Now)+' DeleteThread (CalcTree) :- ERROR: ' + E.Message), ServerAccessLog);
    EXIT;
  END; // Exception
end;

I have logged this exception in my access logs. The log was created as below.

28.10.2024 10.28.22 DeleteThread (CalcTree) :- ERROR: CheckSynchronize called from thread $5994, which is NOT the main thread

Here one observation is, in the same deleting method we have another code block for freeing an FDConnection object. That block is executing without any exceptions. I am adding that code also here for your reference:
try
  // Working perfectly
  FDConnection1.Free;
  FDQuery1.Free;
  FDTable1.Free;
except
  ON E: Exception DO BEGIN
    TBCmd5.WriteLogDo(ServerPointer, (DateTimeToStr(Now)+' DeleteThread (FDObjects) :- ERROR: ' + E.Message), ServerAccessLog);
    EXIT;
  END; // Exception
end;

I tried to add a parent while creating the CalcTree object, but the issue still exists.
I also tried to use the Dispose method instead of Free for the CalcTree object, but still the issue is raised.
Can anyone explain what the reason for this exception could be, and how we can resolve this issue?
New Update:
Thank you all for you valuable comments and suggestions. I am finally able to resolve the issue by adding my calctree.Destroy method inside the synchronize method. Then the exception never raised.
The updated code is as below.
try
    TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
    begin
      CalcTree.Destroy;
    end)
  except
    ON E: Exception DO BEGIN
      TBCmd5.WriteLogDo(ServerPointer, (DateTimeToStr(Now)+' DeleteThread (CalcTree) :- ERROR: ' + E.Message), ServerAccessLog);
      EXIT;
    END; // Exception
  end;


The error message is pretty clear. You are releasing CalcTree object from background thread instead of main thread. You should synchronize CalcTree.Free call with main thread using TThread.Synchronize or TThread.Queue

I didn't understand how to identify which one is main thread and which one is background thread. Can you please suggest how do that?

There is not enough context to see where you are calling Free and how it is being called from the background thread. One possibility is that you are creating thread and running that code from thread, or TVirtualStringTree uses threads (I am not that familiar with it to tell you more, but from what I know it does use threads in some parts) You can read how to provide [mre] to improve the question.

I'm more concerned that CalcTree is trying to call CheckSynchronize during its destruction in the first place. Also, that a UI control is being used outside of the main UI thread. These are not good design choices.

Using a GUI control non-visually to store data is wrong. Use a proper data structure. UI controls are meant to run in the main thread and present data to the user.

There are more questions here for that issue: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TThread+checksynchronize+

Can you build with debug DCUs, then trace what TThread.CheckSynchronize does? It returns false or an unexpected integer value, maybe you can find out which Check fails....

Thank you all for your valuable suggestions and points. I am finally able to resolve the issue by adding my clactree.destroy call inside the synchronize method. Then the exception is not happened.  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
begin
CalcTree.Destroy;
end)
